# Comparing Two Methods for Loading Data from SQL Server to Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: c#, redis, azure-data-factory, azure-redis-cache

My goal is to transfer a million records from my SQL Server database to an Azure Cache for Redis. I cannot do this in one go, so I have split the SET operation into smaller batches. I am looking for the best method to manage this transfer.

**Option 1:** I create a simple C# application that loads each record into Redis as shown in the code snippet.

```
using StackExchange.Redis;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string cacheConnection = "your_connection_string_here";

        // Connect to Azure Redis Cache
        ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
        IDatabase cache = connection.GetDatabase();

        // loading data from SQL Server
        var dataFromSqlServer = GetRowsFromSqlServer();

        // Cache each row individually
        foreach (var row in dataFromSqlServer)
        {
            cache.StringSet($"myKey:{row.Id}", row.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Data cached successfully!");
    }
}
```

The problem is what happens if my application fails halfway. Do I have to start over? I could use a filter based on the creation date of the SQL Server record and save checkpoints, but I think there is a better way.

**Option 2:** I use Azure Data Factory to load the million records and then call Redis API for each record. Are there any disadvantages to using ADF?

Comment: What if ADF fails half way? Why load so much data into a cache anyway? Normally we try to optimize that by only loading really relevant, well-used data; data that will be read 0 or 1 times is highly unlikely to benefit from being cached, because the effort of reading it from the data store, writing to the cache and reading from the cache is likely greater  than just reading it from the data store if it is ever needed

Comment: Read the rows in order of the clustering key of the table, and keep track (in the cache?) of where you were up to with the read. If there is a failure, resume from that point?